# Forking child process and C++ objects

Tags: c++, linux

I have several questions. Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

- Do C++ classes survive forking?
- If so, how it is implemented?
- What happens to pointers? Entire free store/heap is replicated and all virtual addresses are preserved?
- What happens to file streams?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my understanding:

- Do C++ classes survive forking?

yes.

- If so, how it is implemented?

All of memory is copied so you have no trouble there.

- What happens to pointers? Entire free store/heap is replicated and all virtual addresses are preserved?

yes.

- What happens to file streams?

Both processes retain a copy of all open filestreams. (by default there are some fork options that can change this I think.)
Streams opened after fork are not shared.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, be aware that this behavior is *extremely* platform-dependent.  If you are asking out of anything other than idle curiosity, may I suggest you re-think your design?

That said, what is and is not preserved by fork is specified by [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html).  How to interpret this for C++ depends on how exactly your C++ (userspace) runtime is implemented.

File streams are an interesting case.  The underlying file descriptor will get cloned, so both processes will have an open descriptor.  But the user-space buffer (if there is one) will most likely get *duplicated*.  So, for instance:

```
std::cout << "Hello!";
fork();
std::cout << std::endl;
```

...has a pretty good chance of printing `Hello!` twice, simply because the buffer will get copied (along with everything else in the address space of the process).

In short, I would answer your questions as:

- It depends on the class and what you mean by "survive".
- It is implemented by duplicating the entire virtual address space of the process, among other things.
- Pointers keep their values, and what they point to gets duplicated.  (This is done "lazily"; i.e. as "copy on write", so it is not as inefficient as it probably sounds)
- (re: file streams) See above.

Comment: The tag does say "Linux", so the platform is relatively specific. Nice example with the buffered output.

Comment: @Kerrek: Except the details could easily change with new versions of Linux + g++.  It really depends on how the runtime interacts with the kernel.  For instance, do you know what happens to futexes during fork()?  I don't...

Comment: Hehe - does anyone? :-) The quote goes on, "The entire virtual address space of the parent is replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes, condition variables, and other pthreads objects", but no idea if that subsumes futexes...

Comment: @Kerrek:  Yeah.  I guess my point is that POSIX is really a C standard, not a C++ standard.  So interactions with the C++ standard library are really not specified.

Comment: @Nemo aren't standard C streams (`FILE*`) also buffered?  In this case, you could get the same effect, couldn't you?

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be answered by typing `man fork`:

- "The  child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors."
- "The entire virtual address space of the parent is replicated in the child"

Basically, the child process will be in the exact same state as the parent (but see the man page for a long list of exceptions to this vastly oversimplified statement).

How is it implemented? What level of detail do you want? The memory might be implemented as copy-on-write. But that's not of your concern, the child process simply gets an exact copy of the entire memory.